# Composite Pattern with Restriction

Tags: design-patterns, composite

The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwfyS.png) is an example of Composite Pattern.

However I have a restriction, that is that ConcreteComponent1 can only have ONE ConcreteComponent2.

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Thanks!

(Sorry but stackoverflow didnt let me include the picture here)

Answer (score 1):

Three options when clients attempt to add a second `ConcreteComponent2`:

1. Keep the first instance and ignore the second.
2. Replace the first instance with the second.
3. Throw an exception.

Whatever you do, document it, so the behavior doesn't come as a surprise to clients.